# Employees and Organizational Hierarchy

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns

Employee hierarchy in an Organization is classic example of modeling Composite design  pattern. Following are the details that are to be modeled:

1. There are two type of employees; Manager, and Developer.
2. A Manager manages a team that can comprise managers, and developer.
3. A Developer has fixed salary at given point of time and get work from the manager.
4. The salary of a manager is the sum of salary of all the team members + 10K.
5. We need to model work distribution, and salary of employees of the organization.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Employee {
   private:
      string _name;
   public:
      Employee(string name_) {
         _name = name_;
      }
      string name() {
         return _name;
      }
      void virtual work() = 0; 
      float virtual salary() = 0;
};
// Common Interface to interact with Manager, and Developer
class Developer : public Employee {
   private:
      float _salary;
   public:
      Developer(string name_,float salary_) : Employee(name_),_salary(salary_) {}
      void work() {
         cout << "Developer " << name() << " Worked\n";
         // A developer works own.
      }
      float salary() {
         return _salary;
      }
};

class Manager : public Employee {
   private:
      vector<Employee*> _team; 
   public:
      Manager(string name_) : Employee(name_) {}
      void add(Employee * emp_) {
          _team.push_back(emp_);
      } 
      void work() {
         cout << "Manager " << name() << " Distributed Work\n"; 
         for(vector<Employee*>::iterator it = _team.begin(); it!=_team.end(); ++it) {
            (*it)->work();
         }
         // A manager distributes work in team members.
      }
      float salary() {
         float salary_ = 0.0;
         for(vector<Employee*>::iterator it = _team.begin(); it!=_team.end(); ++it) {
            salary_ += (*it)->salary()+15000;
         }
         return salary_;
         // Salary of a manager is derived from team members.
      }
};
int main() {
   Developer d1("developer1",10000);
   Developer d2("developer2",15000);
   Manager m1("manager1");
   m1.add(&d1);
   m1.add(&d2);
   Manager m2("manager2");
   m2.add(&m1);
   m2.work();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Don't use `using namespace std`

That's generally considered bad practice.

Rather use

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
```

if you want to avoid typing these out.

#### 2. Use interfaces properly and don't mix them up with *abstract* class implementations

1. Instead of simply declaring an abstract class, sort out specific interfaces in 1st place

   ```
   struct IEmployee {
         virtual const& string name() const = 0; // see 3. regarding const please
         virtual const float& salary() const = 0;
         virtual bool managesOtherEmployees() const = 0; // equivalent to isLeaf() in the
                                                         // common composite pattern
                                                         // examples
         virtual void work() = 0; 
   };
   ```
2. Add functionality as needed:

   ```
   struct IManager {
       void add(IEmployee&) = 0;
       void delete(IEmployee&) = 0; // if you have functions to extend the
                                    // composition, you probably want to have
                                    // the reverse operation if reasonable.
                                    // Here it seems to be so, since managers 
                                    // sometimes need to fire team members.
   };
   ```
3. Provide the abstract class for the common implementation

   ```
   class Employee : public IEmployee {
   private:
       string name_; // Don't use prefix '_' for symbols, these are reserved 
                       // for the compiler and standard library implementations (see 4.)
       float salary_;
   public:
       Employee(string name, float salary) : name_(name), salary_(salary) {}
       string name() const override {
           return name_;
       }
       float salary() const override {
           return salary_;
       }
       bool managesOtherEmployees() const override { return false; }
   };
   ```

***2.*** leads to an implementation of `Developer` and `Manager` classes as follows:

```
class Developer : public Employee {
public:
    Developer(string name,float salary) : Employee(name,salary) {}
    void work() {
         cout << "Developer " << name() << " Worked\n";
         // A developer works own.
    }
};

class Manager : public Employee, public IManager {
private:
    vector<std::reference_wrapper<IEmployee>> team_; 
public:
    Manager(string name, float salary) : Employee(name,salary) {}
    bool managesOtherEmployees() const override { return true; }
    void add(IEmployee& emp) override {
        team_.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<IEmployee>(emp));
    } 
    void delete(IEmployee& emp) override {
        std::remove(team_.begin(),team_.end(),std::reference_wrapper<IEmployee>(emp));
    }
    void work() {
        cout << "Manager " << name() << " Distributed Work\n"; 
        for(auto& emp : team_) { // Use range based loops and auto whenever possible (see 5.)
            emp.work();
        }
        // A manager distributes work in team members.
     }
     float salary() const override {
        float accumulatedSalary = 0.0;
        for(const auto& emp : team_) { // Note const and reference again
            accumulatedSalary += emp.salary() +15000;
        }
        return accumulatedSalary;
        // Salary of a manager is derived from team members.
     }
};
```

#### 3. Use `const` qualifiers as much as possible

If you're declaring a class operation (class member function), decide if this should change the class state in first place.
Append a `const` qualifier, if you decide it shouldn't.

Same for parameters and return values. Usually you don't have to worry about which method *by value* or *by const reference* will be more efficient.
With any sophisticated, modern c++ compiler, you can assume the most efficient emitted assembly code will be chosen.

Passing/returning by value, still might be prone to generate copies if RVO isn't applicable. Thus I simply prefer to be explicit about that.

#### 4. Don't use symbol names prefixed with `_`

Symbol names prefixed with a single or double underscore (`_`) are preserved by the c++ standard for compiler internals and standard library implementations.

It's easy to come over that just using underscores as a postfix for symbols as indication of class member variables:

```
template<typename TValue>
class MyClass {
private:
     TValue myValue_;
public:
     MyClass(const TValue& myValue) : myValue_(myValue) {}
     const TValue& myValue() { return myValue_; } // standard getter signature
     void myValue(const & TValue value) { myValue_ = value; } // standard setter signature
};
```

The above pattern will serve 98% of cases unambiguously quite well.

#### 5. Use *range based loop* syntax beyond c++98

Since c++11 standard was established, the language supports *range based* `for()` loops of the form

`for(<type spec> el : <container_ref>) { /* ... */ }`

You should use the `auto` keyword for *`<type spec>`*, it can be garnished with `const` and `&` as usual, and automatically evaluates a dereferenced [`Iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) when enumerating the *Containers* values.